# How to animate a split/crack in object

Tags: modeling, animation, workflow

I wish to animate this model so it splits apart/cracks and each piece falls away from each other once it has fallen onto the scene.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/FF4oZUG.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ZCtBhDH.png]

I have also tried to use Cell Fracture, the result is below:

[image]

What would the best way to to approach this problem? I don't want the crack to form until it has fallen down into the scene.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) What have you tried so far? Cell fracture might possibly be manipulated to work here.

Comment: I am using a macbook pro so cell fracture just crashes. I wondered if a boolean animation could be a possible thing. Essentially I want the object to be a solid object until it falls and then that is where I want it to come apart.

Comment: https://imgur.com/GUL2efo heres what it does when I try cell fracture

Comment: Are you still going on this or has it been solved?

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't find a solution, I've tried animating the visibility of a solid heart pendant falling in then replacing it with one that is in two pieces to give the illusion of breaking apart but that didn't work. What would you suggest?

Comment: Mark, that's the way I've been doing things like this, particularly with cell fracture so we don't see the fractures before it's supposed to actually begin falling apart.  I'll see what I can come up with.